# Can Paradox 4.5 be set up on a server?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, paradox, netbeans6.1

I have established a link using Netbeans and Paradox driver and can query the database. Can Paradox 4.5 (Borland) be set up on a server so that the database can be queried remotely?  Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used paradox pretty long ago, so I hope I remember well.

Paradox is not a server based database, but it is file based. That means you do not need paradox at all to use a paradox database. You just need the proper drivers.

In the configuration you specify a network control directory. You have to use the same location for all computers accessing a database. It is the best if you also use the same driveletter.

The database itself should also have the same driveletter and path from all workstations. You can use the same drive which you use for the network control directory.

If you cannot access the database any more, disconnect all workstations from the database, remove *.net (like pdoxusrs.net) and *.lck in the network control directory, and where the table is located. Then try again.

Comment: Take a look at http://support.novell.com/docs/Tids/InfoDocument/1203264.html, I think that page explains it well.